# Querying Json with Linq, Cannot access child value

Tags: c#, json, api, linq

I am new to C# with JSON. I would like to select with Nvidia API, the "featuredProduct" part, but I have an error

> Cannot access child value on Newtonsoft.Json.Linq.JProperty.

This code works for the "searchedProducts" part.

Can you explain to me why?

```
const string url = "";
const int refresh = 3000;

string json = getGpuFromNvidia(url);

var jsonParse = JObject.Parse(json);

var result = jsonParse["searchedProducts"]["featuredProduct"]
    .Where(n => n["isFounderEdition"].Value<bool>() == true)
    .Select(p => new CarteGraphique
    {
        displayName = (string)p["displayName"],
        prdStatus = (string)p["prdStatus"],
        directPurchaseLink = (string)p["retailers"][0]["directPurchaseLink"]
    })
    .ToList();
```

Comment: Why not create a class structure for the JSON you are getting from the API and deserialize the JSON to an object of that class... https://json2csharp.com/ you can use LINQ easily on object collections then JObject and its properties.

Comment: featuredProduct is an one item you can only use select with list of items

Answer (score 1):

I tested this code in VS

```
 string json = ...your code
var jsonObj = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<NvidiaRoot>(json);

var result = jsonObj.searchedProducts.productDetails
    .Where(n => n.isFounderEdition)
    .Select(p => new
    {
    displayName = p.displayName,
    prdStatus = p.prdStatus,
    directPurchaseLink = p.retailers[0].directPurchaseLink
    })
    .ToList();
```

OUTPUT

```
[
    {
        "displayName": "NVIDIA RTX 3090",
        "prdStatus": "out_of_stock",
        "directPurchaseLink": "https://www.ldlc.com/fiche/PB89455870.html"
    },
    {
        "displayName": "NVIDIA RTX 3070",
        "prdStatus": "out_of_stock",
        "directPurchaseLink": "https://www.ldlc.com/fiche/PB74221588.html"
    },
    {
        "displayName": "NVIDIA RTX 3060 Ti",
        "prdStatus": "out_of_stock",
        "directPurchaseLink": "https://www.ldlc.com/fiche/PB54012144.html"
    },
    {
        "displayName": "NVIDIA RTX 3070 Ti",
        "prdStatus": "out_of_stock",
        "directPurchaseLink": null
    },
    {
        "displayName": "NVIDIA RTX 3080 Ti",
        "prdStatus": "out_of_stock",
        "directPurchaseLink": null
    }
]
```

UPDATE

if you need just a feature product

```
    var featuredProduct = jsonObj.searchedProducts.featuredProduct;
            var result = new
            {
                displayName = featuredProduct.displayName,
                prdStatus = featuredProduct.prdStatus,
                directPurchaseLink = featuredProduct.retailers[0].directPurchaseLink
            };
```

Short OUTPUT

```
{
    "displayName": "NVIDIA RTX 3080",
    "prdStatus": "out_of_stock",
    "directPurchaseLink": "https://www.ldlc.com/fiche/PB15921567.html"
}
```

Full OUTPUT

```
var result = jsonObj.searchedProducts.featuredProduct;

{
    "displayName": "NVIDIA RTX 3080",
    "totalCount": 1,
    "productID": 30045,
    "imageURL": "https://assets.nvidia.partners/images/png/nvidia-geforce-rtx-3080.png",
    "productTitle": "NVIDIA GEFORCE RTX 3080",
    "digitialRiverID": "",
    "productSKU": "NVGFT080",
    "productUPC": "NVGFT080_FR",
    "productUPCOriginal": "NVGFT080",
    "productPrice": "€719.00",
    "productAvailable": false,
    "productRating": null,
    "customerReviewCount": null,
    "isFounderEdition": true,
    "isFeaturedProduct": true,
    "certified": false,
    "manufacturer": "NVIDIA",
    "locale": "FR",
    "isFeaturedProdcutFoundInSecondSearch": false,
    "category": "GPU",
    "gpu": "RTX 3080",
    "purchaseOption": "",
    "prdStatus": "out_of_stock",
    "minShipDays": null,
    "maxShipDays": null,
    "shipInfo": null,
    "isOffer": false,
    "offerText": "",
    "retailers": [
        {
            "productId": 30045,
            "productTitle": "NVIDIA GEFORCE RTX 3080",
            "logoUrl": "https://assets.nvidia.partners/logos/geforce/retailer-ldlc.png",
            "isAvailable": true,
            "salePrice": "719.00",
            "directPurchaseLink": "https://www.ldlc.com/fiche/PB15921567.html",
            "purchaseLink": "https://www.ldlc.com/fiche/PB15921567.html",
            "hasOffer": false,
            "offerText": null,
            "partnerId": "45",
            "storeId": "45",
            "upc": "NVGFT080_FR",
            "sku": "NVGFT080",
            "stock": 0,
            "retailerName": "https://www.ldlc.com",
            "type": 80
        }
    ],
    "productInfo": [
        {
            "name": "cooling_system",
            "value": "Fan"
        },
        {
            "name": "gpu_boost_clock_speed",
            "value": "1.71 GHz"
        },
        {
            "name": "gpu_memory_size",
            "value": "10 GB"
        }
    ],
    "compareProductInfo": [
        {
            "name": "cooling_system",
            "value": "Fan"
        },
        {
            "name": "gpu_clock_speed",
            "value": "1.44 GHz"
        },
        {
            "name": "gpu_boost_clock_speed",
            "value": "1.71 GHz"
        },
        {
            "name": "gpu_memory_size",
            "value": "10 GB"
        }
    ]
}
```

classes

```
    public class NvidiaRoot
    {
        public object categories { get; set; }
        public List<Filter> filters { get; set; }
        public object filterGroups { get; set; }
        public object search { get; set; }
        public string version { get; set; }
        public List<Sort> sort { get; set; }
        public Pagination pagination { get; set; }
        public SearchedProducts searchedProducts { get; set; }
        public Disclaimer disclaimer { get; set; }
    }

    public class FilterValue
    {
        public string dispValue { get; set; }
        public object dispValueDesription { get; set; }
        public object groupType { get; set; }
        public int units { get; set; }
        public bool @checked { get; set; }
        public object imageURL { get; set; }
        public bool isValidate { get; set; }
    }

    public class Filter
    {
        public string displayName { get; set; }
        public string filterField { get; set; }
        public string displayMaxValues { get; set; }
        public string fieldType { get; set; }
        public int? selectedMinRangeVal { get; set; }
        public int? selectedMaxRangeVal { get; set; }
        public int? defaultMinRangeVal { get; set; }
        public int? defaultMaxRangeVal { get; set; }
        public string unitsOfMeasure { get; set; }
        public bool @checked { get; set; }
        public object units { get; set; }
        public List<FilterValue> filterValues { get; set; }
        public string dataType { get; set; }
        public bool showCount { get; set; }
        public int filterDisplayOrder { get; set; }
    }

    public class Sort
    {
        public string displayName { get; set; }
        public string value { get; set; }
        public bool selected { get; set; }
    }

    public class Pagination
    {
        public int page { get; set; }
        public int limit { get; set; }
        public int totalRecords { get; set; }
        public bool featuredProductIncludedInCount { get; set; }
    }

    public class Retailer
    {
        public int productId { get; set; }
        public string productTitle { get; set; }
        public string logoUrl { get; set; }
        public bool isAvailable { get; set; }
        public string salePrice { get; set; }
        public string directPurchaseLink { get; set; }
        public string purchaseLink { get; set; }
        public bool hasOffer { get; set; }
        public object offerText { get; set; }
        public string partnerId { get; set; }
        public string storeId { get; set; }
        public string upc { get; set; }
        public string sku { get; set; }
        public int stock { get; set; }
        public string retailerName { get; set; }
        public int type { get; set; }
    }

    public class ProductInfo
    {
        public string name { get; set; }
        public string value { get; set; }
    }

    public class CompareProductInfo
    {
        public string name { get; set; }
        public string value { get; set; }
    }

    public class FeaturedProduct
    {
        public string displayName { get; set; }
        public int totalCount { get; set; }
        public int productID { get; set; }
        public string imageURL { get; set; }
        public string productTitle { get; set; }
        public string digitialRiverID { get; set; }
        public string productSKU { get; set; }
        public string productUPC { get; set; }
        public string productUPCOriginal { get; set; }
        public string productPrice { get; set; }
        public bool productAvailable { get; set; }
        public object productRating { get; set; }
        public object customerReviewCount { get; set; }
        public bool isFounderEdition { get; set; }
        public bool isFeaturedProduct { get; set; }
        public bool certified { get; set; }
        public string manufacturer { get; set; }
        public string locale { get; set; }
        public bool isFeaturedProdcutFoundInSecondSearch { get; set; }
        public string category { get; set; }
        public string gpu { get; set; }
        public string purchaseOption { get; set; }
        public string prdStatus { get; set; }
        public object minShipDays { get; set; }
        public object maxShipDays { get; set; }
        public object shipInfo { get; set; }
        public bool isOffer { get; set; }
        public string offerText { get; set; }
        public List<Retailer> retailers { get; set; }
        public List<ProductInfo> productInfo { get; set; }
        public List<CompareProductInfo> compareProductInfo { get; set; }
    }

    public class ProductDetail
    {
        public string displayName { get; set; }
        public int totalCount { get; set; }
        public int productID { get; set; }
        public string imageURL { get; set; }
        public string productTitle { get; set; }
        public string digitialRiverID { get; set; }
        public string productSKU { get; set; }
        public string productUPC { get; set; }
        public string productUPCOriginal { get; set; }
        public string productPrice { get; set; }
        public bool productAvailable { get; set; }
        public object productRating { get; set; }
        public object customerReviewCount { get; set; }
        public bool isFounderEdition { get; set; }
        public bool isFeaturedProduct { get; set; }
        public bool certified { get; set; }
        public string manufacturer { get; set; }
        public string locale { get; set; }
        public bool isFeaturedProdcutFoundInSecondSearch { get; set; }
        public string category { get; set; }
        public string gpu { get; set; }
        public string purchaseOption { get; set; }
        public string prdStatus { get; set; }
        public object minShipDays { get; set; }
        public object maxShipDays { get; set; }
        public object shipInfo { get; set; }
        public bool isOffer { get; set; }
        public string offerText { get; set; }
        public List<Retailer> retailers { get; set; }
        public List<ProductInfo> productInfo { get; set; }
        public List<CompareProductInfo> compareProductInfo { get; set; }
    }

    public class SearchedProducts
    {
        public int totalProducts { get; set; }
        public bool featuredProductIncludedInCount { get; set; }
        public bool featuredProductsFlag { get; set; }
        public FeaturedProduct featuredProduct { get; set; }
        public List<ProductDetail> productDetails { get; set; }
        public List<object> suggestedProductDetails { get; set; }
    }

    public class Disclaimer
    {
        public string text { get; set; }
    }
```

Comment: Thank you for the answer.
The json deserialization function need to create such a heavy class architecture? Because I only need 3 fields.
In this case, the deserialization function is still the right solution?

My problem is to bring together the data of the FeaturedProduct and the SearchedProducts.
in your example, the FeaturedProduct (rtx 3080) is not listed.

thank you in advance

Answer (score 0):

You can try the below code.

To get the Featured Product. Sample Working code [Here](https://dotnetfiddle.net/kFb73A)

```
var jsonParse = JObject.Parse(json);

var featuredProduct = jsonParse["searchedProducts"]["featuredProduct"];
var f = new CarteGraphique
{
     displayName = featuredProduct["displayName"].ToString(),
     prdStatus = featuredProduct["prdStatus"].ToString(),
     directPurchaseLink = featuredProduct["retailers"][0]["directPurchaseLink"].ToString()
};
Console.WriteLine("Featured Product Details : " + f.displayName + ", " + f.prdStatus + ", " + f.directPurchaseLink);
```